# Querying for recent transactions and balance of third party account

Tags: curl, paypal

I've been trying to get my head around the Paypal API the last few days and its been a struggle.

My ultimate end goal is to be able to read recent transactions and the balance of a third parties paypal account.

I've set up a paypal developer account and app with my business paypal and created a sandbox account which I've acquired a username, password and signature.

I've noticed there are two types of API's :

- REST API
- Classic API ('NVP' API and 'SOAP' API)

Using Paypals permission service documented [here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/permissions-service/integration-guide/PermissionsUsing/) I successfully accrued an access token through Curl using my username, password and signature of my sandbox account and directing the user to Paypals website then back to mine to untimely to acquire the token.

This access token can be used to make API calls on behalf of the user.

I've found a 'Merchant API' within the classic API section [here](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/GetBalance_API_Operation_NVP/) labelled GetBalance and allows me to receive the balance for a paypal account. This API is labelled a Name-Value Pair API and you can't seem to use an access token and must use username, password and a signature.

The access tokens works with REST API's but I can't see any operations that would allow me to see recent transactions or current balance.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you went through the "[make your first call](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/make-your-first-call/)" tutorial, which does indeed use the REST API, and that token would not work with the Classic API.

For the Classic API, you need to use the [Permissions API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/button-manager/integration-guide/SOAP/ButtonMgrOverview/), which is a similar process, but for Classic instead of REST.  The token you get back from that would work with Classic API calls.

The Classic API is still quite a bit more mature than the REST API, so I still personally prefer it.

The [API Reference](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/) is your best friend for browsing through Classic API calls.  To get a list of transactions you would use the [TransactionSearch](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/DoReferenceTransaction_API_Operation_SOAP/) and/or [GetTransactionDetails](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/GetTransactionDetails_API_Operation_SOAP/).

Once a user has granted permissions for your app (api username) to make calls on their behalf you would pass their PayPal account email or merchant ID into the SUBJECT parameter in the request as an extra credential along with the API username, password, and signature.  That's not very reliable, though, because people usually use their email address there and then will often change their email address in PayPal but forget to update your app.  That's where the [Permissions API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/permissions/RequestPermissions_API_Operation/) comes in to play, and instead of passing the SUBJECT parameter in the actual request string you would add additional headers in the request with the token.

It's all explained pretty well in their [Permissions documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/permissions-service/integration-guide/PermissionsUsing/).

Comment: That makes things a little more clear however I can't find anyway in the classic API to view recent transactions or balance. There are merchant API's however they don't use a access token through the permissions service and use merchant credentials.